# to find whether its day or night using time() module in python

Tags: python, time

I started to write

```
import time
localtime = time.localtime()
print(localtime)
```

but the localtime gives nine attributes

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=22, 
                 tm_min=32, tm_sec=41, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=212, tm_isdst=1)
```

I want to find whether its am or pm in python by comparing hours:min:sec with the local time. Please suggest

Comment: "am/pm" is much easier than "day or night". Assuming it's the former you need, it is as easy as seeing if `tm_hour` is twelve or more.

Comment: You also have to take into consideration what is Day and Night? In some places, it gets dark much earlier than others, so their night begins sooner than you may think. If you set up a generic value to be night time and a generic value to be day time, you could say that night time in your code is 8pm but in some places it is already dark by 7pm.

Comment: i am just a beginner so at this time, i will go with the am, pm and then later on i will see day or night. Anyways thanks for your suggestions

Comment: how to compare tm_hour is twelve or more

Comment: The best way to do day or night is to have a light sensor somewhere outside feeding into your Python program. Then you don't *need* to worry about time of the year or latitude. Of course, you *do* then need to worry about clouds and/or some ugly beast deciding to sit down on your sensor :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
tm_hour=22
```

*This* is the field you're interested in<sup>(a)</sup>, and you can get at the individual fields just by using (e.g., for the hour) `localtime.tm_hour`.

You can then use it to figure out what part of the day it is, as follows:

```
0 - 11 -> am, 12 - 23 -> pm
```

A simple bit of code for this would be:

```
import time
mytime = time.localtime()
if mytime.tm_hour < 12:
    print ('It is AM')
else:
    print ('It is PM')
```

For something more airy-fairy (like day and night), the simplest solution would be fixed times like:

```
0 - 5, 19 - 23 -> night, 6 - 18 -> day
```

done with:

```
import time
mytime = time.localtime()
if mytime.tm_hour < 6 or mytime.tm_hour > 18:
    print ('It is night-time')
else:
    print ('It is day-time')
```

That, of course, depends entirely on how you *define* day and night since the sun rises and sets at different times in different parts of the world at different times of the year and, in extreme cases of far-north and far-south latitudes, sometimes not for months at a time.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Technically you probably should be using hour, minute and possibly even second, since it can be argued that both midday and midnight are neither ante-meridian nor post-meridian. But we'll go with simpler solutions in the context of this question.

Sample code, ignoring seconds, follows:

```
import time
mytime = time.localtime()
myhour = mytime.tm_hour
mymin = mytime.tm_min
if myhour == 0 and mymin == 0:
    print('It is midnight')
elif myhour < 12:
    print ('It is AM')
elif myhour == 12 and mymin == 0:
    print('It is noon')
else:
    print ('It is PM')
```

Comment: how to access tm_hour

Comment: @FPeracha, added details on that.